# Get File Name via Index

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file

I want to get a file from the index... so say there was a folder, and I wanted to get the first file in that folder and put the name in a string. Is there a function for that?

Comment: You'll probably find this page helpful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So that others can judge whether @Mike's link really would be helpful for them: it goes to a page demonstrating how to list the files in a directory with `FindFirstFile` et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx) API function returns what the file system considers to be the first file in the directory. If you want some later file, proceed to call `FindNextFile` the appropriate number of times. In any case, call `FindClose` afterward.

For NTFS, directories store their file names in sorted order. It might not be the order you want to display them in, though. For FAT, I think file names are stored in roughly the order they were created in. Deleting a file and then creating a new one might disrupt that order. Other local and network file systems might use still other orderings.

If you want files to be in a particular order, the better thing to do is to call `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` until you've gotten *all* the files in a directory, and then sort them according to whatever criteria you really need instead of relying on the underlying file system.